# List<string> removeat

Tags: c#

I want to remove strings in a List that length is lower than 50:

```
example@gmail.com:123456789 <---- 17
example1111@gmail.com:123456789 <---- 21
example1@gmail.com:123456789 <---- 18
example111@gmail.com:123456789 <---- 20
```

the string after the ":" doesn't count.

here is my code:

```
if (emaillower != 0)  // emaillower = the length
{
    string pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9@.]+[:]";
    for (int i = 0; i < OldCombo.Count; i++)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(OldCombo[i], pattern);
        if (m.Success && m.Length <= emaillower)
            OldCombo.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
foreach(string s in OldCombo)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Current output:

```
example1111@gmail.com:123456789
example:111@gmail.com:123456789
```

Wanted output:

```
everything needs to be remove
```

Comment: Your pattern only allows ASCII chars. Where I live, we call that "asking-for-trouble-code".

Comment: I wouldn't use regex here - just Split or SubString or IndexOf - makes it much simpler

Comment: When you remove an item you need to decrement `i` because everything after that position has been moved to a lower index.

Comment: @juharr Maybe opinion, but following NibblyPig's answer and working through it back to front seems less error prone to me.

Comment: @Fildor Both ways will work.  There's a little less code involved if you iterate backwards.  The main take away is that the index of items are changing and you have to take that into account somehow.

Comment: @juharr They will work, yes. It's just somehow, I cringe when I see myself forced to mingle with the loop counter inside the loop... as I said. Maybe a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also use the method RemoveAll like this:

```
private void DoStuff ()
{
    if (emaillower != 0)  // emaillower = the length
    {            
        OldoCombo.RemoveAll (x => Match(x, emaillower )); 
    }
    foreach(string s in OldCombo)
        Console.WriteLine(s);

}

private bool Match (string value, int maxLength)
{
    string pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9@.]+[:]";;
    Match match = Regex.Match(value, pattern);
    return match.Success && match.Length < maxLength;
}
```

Comment: This is clearly the best solution - it's exactly the sort of thing that `List<T>.RemoveAll()` was designed for. It's also MUCH more performant than removing items in a loop, since it has worst-case O(N) complexity rather than the loop's worst-case O(N^2) complexity. (Because RemoveAt() has O(N) complexity, and it could be called N times for O(N^2) complexity.)

Comment: The idea is there some efforts must be done on the Regex usage.

Comment: Maybe the Substring-Version in NibblyPig's answer would be a good way to avoid regex? But that part wasn't asked in the question anyway. But I agree it can cause issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I get error from the Regex.Match:
an object reference is required for the non-static field, method , or property 'Regex.Match(string)'

Comment: I edited my answer maybe it could help you otherwise you could use the substring version.

Answer (score 3):

If you modify a collection you're iterating over, you're going to have a bad time.

If you have this list:

```
0: Apple
1: Banana
2: Pear
3: Grape
```

If you remove item at position 1, then you end up with:

```
0: Apple
1: Pear
2: Grape
```

If you then remove item at position 2, to remove Pear, you actually remove Grape instead because everything moved.

My suggestion would be to reverse your loop, so it counts backwards.

```
for (int i = OldCombo.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(OldCombo[i], pattern);
    if (m.Success && m.Length <= emaillower)
        OldCombo.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This will mean that if you remove an item it doesn't affect the other positions of the items in the list.

Once you've fixed this issue you need to look at the value of `m` to make sure the regex is returning the part of the string you expect it to.

I can see that if you run it, `m` is coming back as the match, "example@gmail.com:123456789" would give **example@gmail.com:** so as long as `emaillower` is correct it should be OK.

I would recommend changing `m.Length` to `m.Value.Length`, for clarity, even though `m.Length` appears to work.

If you wanted to improve the efficiency further, you could consider using LINQ which would do the entire thing in one line - minus the implied e-mail validation that your regex is doing.

```
var results = OldCombo.Where(c => c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf(':')).Length >= 50);
```

You could also build the regex into the query:

```
var results = OldCombo.Where(c => Regex.Match(c, pattern).Success && c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf(':')).Length >= 50);
```

Comment: You really need to indent the line after the `if` or better yet put it in curly braces.

Comment: Yep, my bad, fixed it now

Comment: Why would LINQ improve the `efficiency`?

Comment: LINQ is generally more optimised, but in this case I sorta meant efficiency in terms of writing code. Generally less is more, especially if it's more readable.